# Is it possible to answer a Skype for Business call from the locked screen?

Tags: windows-10, lync, skype-for-business

Is it possible to answer a Skype **for Business** call (or Lync, as they are closely related) directly from the lock screen of Windows **10** (on a PC)? This would be similar to the functionality available on mobile phones.

The following system setting does not help

[image]

so I believe that this is either impossible (forbidden) by design, deeply hidden or requires an extra app (which would be OK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can answer from a separate desk phone or a mobile Skype4b client but not the Windows client.

Comment: I do not have a desk phone anymore and I am rarely logged into the mobile client. I was really hopeful for a useful "swipe to answer" feature in the PC.

Comment: It's more around security - you can use something like a blync light to identify the ring but you need to be logged in to answer.  The mobile client shouldn't timeout and you can grab the inbound call on it.

Comment: This is not different from the security of a mobile: you get to see who is calling and are able to answer the call. But anyway - if there is no solution never mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you use a Lync / SfB Certified headset with inline controls, you can answer the call using those controls while your PC is locked.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to know who is calling and not answer blindly (similar to a mobile call with locked screen)

Answer (score 0):

As a solution-provider we have developed the Tool "**Enterprise Voice Essentials**". They make it possible to bring the **default toast** and **additional informations and control** to the lock-screen. You might want to have a look here:  [Enterprise Voice Essentials](https://www.splendidminds.de/?portfolio=enterprise-voice-essentials).

Comment: Thank you - do you have an English webpage with the description?

Comment: I am sorry I got the notice that late. There is an english version of that page here: https://www.splendidminds.de/?portfolio=enterprise-voice-essentials&lang=en .  Contact me if you have any questions about the product.